# How to integrate Geoid model calculation in android application?

Tags: java, android, gis

I need a calculation for these geoid models:

```
Embeded EGM96 1°x 1° ,
EGM2008 2.5 x 2.5' ,
IGN RAF09 1.5 X 2.0' ,
Geoid 12B - USA ,
HT 2.0 - Canada ,
OSGM15 - Great Britain ,
Geoid Grid - Solvenia ,
PLGEO11 - Poland
```